# What does the "Recertified"-Label mean on a Harddrive?

Tags: hard-drive

Is it the same as "refurbished" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this [link](http://www.ehow.com/about_5585494_recertified-vs_-refurbished.html):

> Most people are not aware that
>   recertified and refurbished are pretty
>   much the same thing. There are usually
>   a few key factors that define the
>   difference between the two terms. The
>   first factor is that recertified
>   products often come with a short
>   warranty against functional defects.
>   The warranty time frame is usually
>   somewhere between 30 to 60 days.
>   Refurbished products however are
>   typically sold "as-is" without a
>   warranty

For more info check out the link.